# Add Screenresolutions to Ubuntu 14.04 automatically with xrandr

Tags: ubuntu, screen-resolution, xrandr

I use Ubuntu 14.04 with a Laptop and an external screen with a resolution of 1600x900. On the original installation the resolution is limited to 1024x768. So I configured a script that runs automatically on booting using xrandr:

```
#/bin/bash 
xrandr -s 0 
xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync 
xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1600x900_60.00"
```

When the machine is booting and I connect the VGA cable it works fine. When the screen ist conected and I boot or reboot the computer this error appears:

> could not assign CRTCs to outputs: Trying modes for CRTC 63 CRTC 63:
>   trying mode 1600x900@60Hz with output at 1600x900@60Hz (pass 0)
>       none of the selected modes were compatible with the possible modes: Trying modes for CRTC 63 CRTC 63: trying mode 1024x768@60Hz
>   with output at 1600x900@60Hz (pass 0) CRTC 63: trying mode
>   800x600@60Hz with output at 1600x900@60Hz (pass 0) CRTC 63: trying
>   mode 800x600@56Hz with output at 1600x900@60Hz (pass 0) CRTC 63:
>   trying mode 848x480@60Hz with output at 1600x900@60Hz (pass 0) CRTC
>   63: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1600x900@60Hz (pass 0)
>   CRTC 63: trying mode 1024x768@60Hz with output at 1600x900@60Hz (pass
>   1) CRTC 63: trying mode 800x600@60Hz with output at 1600x900@60Hz
>   (pass 1) CRTC 63: trying mode 800x600@56Hz with output at
>   1600x900@60Hz (pass 1) CRTC 63: trying mode 848x480@60Hz with output
>   at 1600x900@60Hz (pass 1) CRTC 63: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with
>   output at 1600x900@60Hz (pass 1) Trying modes for CRTC 64 ...

Is there a solution to make work this script without conecting and disconecting the cable on every boot or reboot?

Comment: You should rather ask at [Superuser](http://superuser.com/) or [Askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I got it! It is a hardware problem: I changed the cable and Ubuntu detects the screen model perfectly and applies the correct resolution even without the script.